# Best practice for filtering data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, faceted-search

I am looking into best -practices for returning search results. I have a search page that subscribes to a publication that returns a find based on the searched regex query in multiple fields. This gets put into the minimongo collection, on the client.

At this time, the way it is being handled is that facets are being set up from the subscription. My question is if the filtering for the pre-loaded results from the backend should be done client side, or if the query should be sent back.

Example :

Given a collection of fruits, i want to find all that have the color red. The server returns this, but I have facets based on the fruits. So, i have a checkbox for strawberries, apples, cherries, etc. If I click on the checkbox for cherries, should I just be filtering the current minimongo collection, or should I re-query?

Logically, I already have all the needed items in my collection that I could be filtering on, so I am not sure why I would need to hit the back-end. The only time I should hit the backend is if in the search, I type in a new query (such as blue), and the facets get re-done appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original search is returning *all* matching documents then adding criteria on the client can just be done in your minimongo query **if** the fields on which the additional criteria were returned with the original search.

OTOH if the original search is returning a paginated list or just the top N results or if the required keys weren't included then you want to continue the search on the server.

In a traditional request-response system, you might also want to query the server each time if the underlying data was rapidly changing (ex: a reservations system). With Meteor the *reactive* nature of pub-sub means that the data on the client is being constantly refreshed with adds/changes/deletions via DDP over WebSocket.

Comment: Currently, I have a flattened collection specifically made to speed up searching by containing only the fields that are directly shown in the search, indexed on the facets. faceting is done with only a subset of those fields. You are correct, once pagination happens, I will hit the server back, but for now, we are sending all matching items. The textfield needs at least 3 chars in order to hit the server though, so at least this returns a subset.